# Regenerate the same layout

Tags: java, android, button, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I'm a beginner here. Now I need to regenerate the same layout(Red box) on button click(black box) how I  should do it.  [My screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtsh9.jpg) . I wrote the code in the recycler view adapter. "shop_anotherblock" is the button where I want to regenerate the layout(Redbox) .code inside the particular on click is the code just I tried. Expand_layout is an XML page where I have a design exactly inside the Redbox. It will be very helpful if anyone helps me here .thanks in advance . And also sorry for code alignment.

This is my code.

```
public class BarberNewScheduleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BarberNewScheduleAdapter.Viewholder> 
{

 private List<RoutineDaysModel> routineday;
String wdays,edit_wdays,StartingTime,EndingTime,WalkApp;

RecylerItemPos mrecylerItemPos;

IntervalTimePickerDialog timePicker2,timePicker1;

private Context context;

public String shop_adapter_starttime,shop_adapter_endtime;

 public BarberNewScheduleAdapter(List<RoutineDaysModel> routineday,RecylerItemPos recylerItemPos){
      mrecylerItemPos = recylerItemPos;
      this.routineday=routineday;
      this.context = context;
```

}

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View itemView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.barber_new_schedule_recview,parent,fasse);
    return new Viewholder(itemView);
}

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder, int position) {
    if(routineday.get(position).getDay()!="Sunday"&&
            routineday.get(position).getDay()!="Monday"&&
            routineday.get(position).getDay()!="Tuesday"&&
            routineday.get(position).getDay()!="Wednesday"&&
            routineday.get(position).getDay()!="Thrusday"&&
            routineday.get(position).getDay()!="Friday"&&
            routineday.get(position).getDay()!="Saturday") {

        wdays = routineday.get(position).getDay();
        StartingTime=routineday.get(position).getStarttime();
        EndingTime=routineday.get(position).getEndtime();
        WalkApp=routineday.get(position).getWalkinappointments();
        holder.setData(wdays,StartingTime,EndingTime,WalkApp);
 }
   else {
        wdays = routineday.get(position).getDay();
        StartingTime=routineday.get(position).getStarttime();
        EndingTime=routineday.get(position).getEndtime();
        WalkApp=routineday.get(position).getWalkinappointments();
        System.out.println("checking221 "+wdays);
        holder.setData(wdays,StartingTime,EndingTime,WalkApp);
        holder.Stime.setText("");
        holder.Etime.setText("");
        holder.WA.setText("");
        holder.notselected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

}

```
    holder.shop_adapter_availtimeSpin1.setText(StartingTime);
    holder.shop_adapter_availtimeSpin2.setText(EndingTime);

holder.shop_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    holder.shop_edit_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.shop_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    wdays=routineday.get(position).getDay();
    BarberNewScheduleActivity.shop_heading.setText("Editing "+wdays+" hours");
    System.out.println("checking_wdays "+wdays);
    holder.edit_weekdays.setText(wdays);

}
```

});

```
holder.shop_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    holder.Stime.setText(shop_adapter_starttime);
    holder.Etime.setText(shop_adapter_endtime);
    holder.shop_edit_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.shop_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   BarberNewScheduleActivity.shop_heading.setText("Here's Your schedule so far");
}
```

});

```
holder.shop_adapter_availtimeSpin1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    holder.refreshTimeSpin();
    timePicker1.show();
}
```

});

```
holder.shop_anotherblock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup parent = v.findViewById(R.id.time_rec);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.expand_layout, parent);
}
```

});

```
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return routineday.size();
}








class Viewholder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView weekdays,Stime,Etime,WA,edit_weekdays,shop_save;
    public LinearLayout notselected;
    public ImageView shop_edit;
    public LinearLayout shop_layout,shop_edit_layout;
    public TextView shop_adapter_availtimeSpin1,shop_adapter_availtimeSpin2;
    public TextView shop_anotherblock;




    public Viewholder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        weekdays=view.findViewById(R.id.Day_recview);
        Stime=view.findViewById(R.id.Day_recview_opentime);
        Etime=view.findViewById(R.id.Day_recview_closetime);
        WA=view.findViewById(R.id.Day_recview_walkinappointments);
        shop_save=view.findViewById(R.id.save_rec);
        notselected=view.findViewById(R.id.notselected);
        shop_edit=view.findViewById(R.id.Day_recview_edit);
        edit_weekdays=view.findViewById(R.id.expand_Day_recview);
        shop_anotherblock= view.findViewById(R.id.block_rec);
        shop_layout=view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_rec);
        shop_edit_layout=view.findViewById(R.id.expand_linearlayout);
        shop_adapter_availtimeSpin2=view.findViewById(R.id.availtimeSpin2_rec);
        shop_adapter_availtimeSpin1=view.findViewById(R.id.availtimeSpin1_rec);


    }
    private  void setData(String daytext,String StimeText,String EtimeText,String WAtext){
        weekdays.setText(daytext);
        Stime.setText(StimeText);
        Etime.setText(EtimeText);
        WA.setText(WAtext);
    }

private void refreshTimeSpin() {
        timePicker1 = new IntervalTimePickerDialog(BarberNewScheduleActivity.mActivity,
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                String timeS=timeconverter(selectedHour,selectedMinute);
                System.out.println(timeS);
                shop_adapter_availtimeSpin1.setText(timeS);
                Stime.setText(timeS);
                shop_adapter_starttime=timeS;

            }
        },7,00,false);

timePicker1.setTitle("");
Objects.requireNonNull(timePicker1.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

timePicker2 = new IntervalTimePickerDialog(BarberNewScheduleActivity.mActivity,
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                String timeS=timeconverter(selectedHour,selectedMinute);
                System.out.println(timeS);
                shop_adapter_availtimeSpin2.setText(timeS);

                shop_adapter_endtime=timeS;
            }
        },20,00,false);

timePicker2.setTitle("");
Objects.requireNonNull(timePicker2.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
shop_adapter_availtimeSpin2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        timePicker2.show();
    }
});
```

}

```
    public String timeconverter(int selectedHour,int selectedMinute){
        System.out.println(" "+selectedHour+" "+selectedMinute);
        String timeS="";
        switch(selectedHour){
            case 1:
                timeS="01";
                break;
            case 2:
                timeS="02";
                break;
            case 3:
                timeS="03";
                break;
            case 4:
                timeS="04";
                break;
            case 5:
                timeS="05";
                break;
            case 6:
                timeS="06";
                break;
            case 7:
                timeS="07";
                break;
            case 8:
                timeS="08";
                break;
            case 9:
                timeS="09";
                break;
            case 10:
                timeS="10";
                break;
            case 11:
                timeS="11";
                break;
            case 12:
                timeS="12";
                break;
            case 13:
                timeS="01";
                break;
            case 14:
                timeS="02";
                break;
            case 15:
                timeS="03";
                break;
            case 16:
                timeS="04";
                break;
            case 17:
                timeS="05";
                break;
            case 18:
                timeS="06";
                break;
            case 19:
                timeS="07";
                break;
            case 20:
                timeS="08";
                break;
            case 21:
                timeS="09";
                break;
            case 22:
                timeS="10";
                break;
            case 23:
                timeS="11";
                break;
            case 0:
                timeS="12";
                break;
        }
        if (selectedMinute==0)
            timeS+=":00";
        else
            timeS+=":30";

        if(selectedHour<12)
            timeS+=" AM";
        else
            timeS+=" PM";
        return timeS;
    }
```

}}

Comment: Have you thought about using <include/> files for your xml?

Comment: didn't try that @KristyWelsh